# can ios safari access bluetooth device?

Tags: ios, safari, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I'm working on a location related project. I found that iOS has iBeacon which can help the app to get the location data. I want to know if iOS Safari does have the access to it? Or any other similar bluetooth device which can be accessed?

Comment: No, there is no access to Core Location Beacon regions (iBeacon) or Core Bluetooth through javascript.  You can access GPS location with user permission

Comment: I mean Javascript in the Safari browser (as this is the context of this question).

Comment: I search apple developer doc.i don't find reference about developing Safari Extensions for IOS

Comment: iOS will never support this because Apple won't implement any standard that will make web apps compete with native apps where they can take 30% off all earnings. So the whole progess of the web will stall because of this if no goverment will intervene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet. There is a proposal in W3C for a "web-bluetooth" specification which has been implemented [Chrome, Edge, Samsung Internet, Opera and chrome-for-android browsers](https://caniuse.com/web-bluetooth). Like all these things, it'll take time for the committees to spin their wheels and for the browser makers to decide if they want to support it , and then implement it.

MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API

Comment: iOS will never support this because Apple won't implement any standard that will make web apps compete with native apps where they can take 30% off all earnings. So the whole progess of the web will stall because of this if no goverment will intervene.

Comment: While I agree with you Roel, we don't *know* that, we  merely suspect it.

Answer (score 4):

Apple don't have this built in to Safari (yet), however there is a Web Browser app called [WebBLE](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/webble/id1193531073?mt=8) that implements 'Web Bluetooth' mentioned by Shayne.

Currently the app only supports a subset of the standard, but it's more than enough for most tasks. It's also Open Source so you could add it to a WebView in your own app if needed.

Having said all that, currently I don't believe Web Bluetooth supports accessing Advertising data - so while you can connect to Bluetooth LE devices and interact with them, you may not be able to get the actual Advertisements (which is kind of the point of iBeacon).